# .NET CORE 3.1 - Entity Framework - IndexOf cannot be mapped

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

When this code is ran, I get the following error message from EF :

**could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Array.IndexOf' failed.**

```
var data = context.TeamMembers.AsQueryable();
data = data.Where(t => Array.IndexOf(someArray, t.Type)>-1);
```

why does it not implements such a simple function ?

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` isn't implemented, but in your case the similar  `IEnumerable.Contains` is implemented

Comment: How would you implement `IndexOf` in SQL?